# Preventing ckeditor to display character on keypress

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

I have a `CKEditor 3.0` instance 'editor' and on its '`key`' event a listener is attached so that when that function is returning `false` it should not type that key character on editor, that is if key 'k' is pressed it should not be displayed on the editor if the function is returning false

```
editor.on('key', function(e)
{
        alert(""+e.data.keyCode);
        return false;
});
```

I used above code for this but it is not working, means the character is getting typed on the editor

Trying the same using a plugin where on keypress of keycode 65 the other language character should show up instead of english language character.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'typing',
    {
        init: function( editor )
        {

            editor.addCommand( 'insertcharacter',
            {
                exec : function( editor )
                {    

                 alert(editor.id);
                    alert(editor.name);
                    editor.on('key', function(e)
                    {
                        alert("Hello"+e.data.keyCode);

                        if(e.data.keyCode == 65)
                        {
                                editor.insertText('Other Language Character');
                        }
                        return false;

                     });
                }
    });
```

can u suggest me any solution for this.
Thanks

Comment: Where is it documented that returning false would prevent the key character from showing up?

Comment: Just considered the java script key event listener

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I misunderstood your question and voted to delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

found the answer recently. this worked for me in the latest version(4.x).

```
editor.document.on('keypress', function(e) {
      e.data.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the default action for any event
      //your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In v4 you can use `editor.on('key')` and `cancel()` the event when the appropriate key is pressed.

So to ignore k keypresses,

```
editor.on('key', function(evt) {
    var keyCodeToIgnore = 'K'.charCodeAt();   // Upper case K. Only one k key.
    var pressedKeyCode = evt.data.keyCode;
    if ( pressedKeyCode === keyCodeToIgnore ) {
        evt.cancel();
    }
}
```

(That wouldn't prevent 'k's being added by other means, of course, such as pasting.)

See http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-key

You can also configure the editor to block specified keystrokes. Using that you can specify case. So to ignore k and not K:

```
config.blockedKeystrokes = [75];    // To ignore k and K: [75, 107]
```

Though you'd probably want to keep the default blockedKeystrokes as well.

See http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-blockedKeystrokes

The first method lets you do other stuff of course. You could drive people crazy by ignoring a 'u' if the previous keypress was a 'q', for example.

Answer (score 0):

use following code before return from function to Cancel/block the character/event.

```
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.returnValue = false;
e.cancel();
e.stop();
return false;
```

where e is in parameter of function

Answer (score 0):

I came looking for a way to bind something to the the enter key press. Except I'm using `contenteditable` div tags, and maybe that made the above solutions not work for me.

However I came to this, that seems to be working perfectly

```
$(function () {
    CKEDITOR.instances['<the DOM ID of your element>'].on('key', function (e) {
        if (e.data.keyCode === 13) {
            //yeet
            e.cancel();
        }
    });
});
```